# EntityGraph and TypedQuery simultaneously

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I'm try to use two Hibernate features simultaneously: `EntityGraph` and Criteria API `TypedQuery` but can't resolve how to use them together:

```
@Override
public List<Customer> findByFilterEntityGraph(final CustomerFilter filter) {
    final EntityManager entityManager = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Customer.class);
    final Root<Customer> customerMetamodel = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
    final Predicate name = criteriaBuilder.like(customerMetamodel.get("name"), filter.getName());
    final Predicate age = criteriaBuilder.between(
            customerMetamodel.get("age"), filter.getAgeFrom(), filter.getAgeTo());
    final Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(name, age);
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

    final TypedQuery<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("customer.products");
    Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);

    // ... ?
    return null;
}
```

I'm sure my `EntityGraph` declared correctly because it's work in other places. But I'm can't find how to use both of them.

I know about approach like this:

```
public Optional<Customer> findByIdEntityGraph(final long customerId) {
    final EntityManager entityManager = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("customer.products");
    Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);
    final Customer customer = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerId, properties);
    return Optional.ofNullable(customer);
}
```

It's allow to using Criteria API with `EntityGraph` but for single result and without condition like filter with `TypedQuery`.

It is possible to use `EntityGraph` and `TypedQuery` together for list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed. I think that you are just wrongly using a fetch graph whereas you should be using a load graph: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm